# Drupal Views - Access control block to change content

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

Is there a way with Views in Drupal (v7, if it's important) to change the content of a block based on access control?

Essentially, what I want to do is always show the block but, if it's an anonymous user accessing the page, display some custom "Access Denied" content. I would think this would be a fairly common thing but I haven't been able to find anything on it.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to do this is by making two blocks. Each block can be restricted to only show for a singular role. So anonymous will see the "access denied message" while "authenticated user" can see your normal view block. This is built in, no plugins required.

Just go to structure -> blocks and add your custom "access denied block" and then limit it to anonymous role. Then change your settings on your views block to only show for the desired role.

Comment: I've considered that but this block has a particular style associated with it that's not easily replicated. I suppose I may need to bite the bullet and copy over the styling as best as I can.

Comment: You should just be able to add some commas to your current CSS. So if you have `.view-content` you can probably change it to `.view-content, #block-block-1` or whatever the name of the block ends up being. In any case, this will probably be a simpler approach then anything else I can think of.